# How To Place Button at AppBar Area?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I saw this in `One Drive` login page.
Custom buttons is placed in buttom area of `AppBar`.

How to achieve this ?

[image: One Drive Login Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, the *AppBar* is system UI and you can't put there customized buttons with official API, only *AppBarButton*.

If you want similar look like this at your picture, you can make your own control which will imitate the AppBar.